# Detecting iBeacon and capturing details in Android

Tags: android, region, ibeacon-android

I am using the proximity-reference-android sample application provided by Radius Network to detect an iBeacon. I have an iPad configured as an iBeacon and have added around 3 beacon regions in the proximity kit. The problem I am facing right now I am unable to fetch the Beacon name ,and the additional url  which I had in the proximity kit in Android.

I need to basically show up the url associated with beacon region in that proximity kit in Android App just like how the iOS application does.

While Debugging I had checked that  even after the beacon is detected in the application,the **didEnterRegion** doesn't get called.I need to basically save the details of that particular beacon in the database once it is detected.

Neither is the application calling **didExitRegion**.

Posting the below code,please let me know what I am doing wrong in this.

```
public class AndroidProximityReferenceApplication extends Application implements
        BootstrapNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidProximityReferenceApplication";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
    private boolean haveDetectedIBeaconsSinceBoot = false;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG,
                "setting up background monitoring for iBeacons and power saving");

        // wake up the app when an iBeacon is seen
        Region region = new Region(
                "com.radiusnetworks.androidproximityreference.backgroundRegion",
                "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6", null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

        // simply constructing this class and holding a reference to it in your
        // custom Application
        // class will automatically cause the iBeaconLibrary to save battery
        // whenever the application
        // is not visible. This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
        // This method is not used in this example
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever
        // an iBeacon
        // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
        Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
        if (!haveDetectedIBeaconsSinceBoot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");

            // The very first time since boot that we detect an iBeacon, we
            // launch the
            // MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // Important: make sure to add android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            // in the manifest
            // to keep multiple copies of this activity from getting created if
            // the user has
            // already manually launched the app.
            this.startActivity(intent);
            haveDetectedIBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
        } else {
            // If we have already seen iBeacons and launched the MainActivity
            // before, we simply
            // send a notification to the user on subsequent detections.
            Log.d(TAG, "Sending notification.");
            ParseObject beacon = new ParseObject("Beacon");
            beacon.put("beacon_name", arg0.getClass().getName());
            beacon.put("beacon_id", arg0.getUniqueId());
            beacon.put("device_type", "Android");
            beacon.put("device_UUID", android.os.Build.MODEL);
            beacon.put("beacon_status", "ENTRY");
            beacon.saveInBackground();

            sendNotification();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "exited region");
        ParseObject beacon = new ParseObject("Beacon");
        beacon.put("beacon_name", arg0.getClass().getName());
        beacon.put("beacon_id", arg0.getUniqueId());
        beacon.put("device_type", "Android");
        beacon.put("device_UUID", android.os.Build.MODEL);
        beacon.put("beacon_status", "ENTRY");
        beacon.saveInBackground();

    }

    private void sendNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setContentTitle("Proximity Reference Application")
                .setContentText("An iBeacon is nearby.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

    }
}
```

The code below is of the **mainActivity** class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IBeaconConsumer,
        RangeNotifier, IBeaconDataNotifier {
    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    IBeaconManager iBeaconManager;
    Map<String, TableRow> rowMap = new HashMap<String, TableRow>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Parse.initialize(this, "test123",
                "test345");
        IBeaconManager.LOG_DEBUG = true;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iBeaconManager = IBeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this
                .getApplicationContext());
        iBeaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onIBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Region region = new Region("MainActivityRanging", null, null, null);
        try {
            iBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            iBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        iBeaconManager.unBind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons,
            Region region) {
        for (IBeacon iBeacon : iBeacons) {
            iBeacon.requestData(this);
            Log.d(TAG, "I see an iBeacon: " + iBeacon.getProximityUuid() + ","
                    + iBeacon.getMajor() + "," + iBeacon.getMinor());
            String displayString = iBeacon.getProximityUuid() + " "
                    + iBeacon.getMajor() + " " + iBeacon.getMinor() + "\n";
            displayTableRow(iBeacon, displayString, false);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void iBeaconDataUpdate(IBeacon iBeacon, IBeaconData iBeaconData,
            DataProviderException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "data fetch error:" + e);
        }
        if (iBeaconData != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "I have an iBeacon with data: uuid="
                            + iBeacon.getProximityUuid() + " major="
                            + iBeacon.getMajor() + " minor="
                            + iBeacon.getMinor() + " welcomeMessage="
                            + iBeaconData.get("welcomeMessage"));
            String displayString = iBeacon.getProximityUuid() + " "
                    + iBeacon.getMajor() + " " + iBeacon.getMinor() + "\n"
                    + "Welcome message:" + iBeaconData.get("welcomeMessage");
            displayTableRow(iBeacon, displayString, true);
        }
    }

    private void displayTableRow(final IBeacon iBeacon,
            final String displayString, final boolean updateIfExists) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.beacon_table);
                String key = iBeacon.getProximity() + "-" + iBeacon.getMajor()
                        + "-" + iBeacon.getMinor();
                TableRow tr = (TableRow) rowMap.get(key);
                if (tr == null) {
                    tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    rowMap.put(key, tr);
                    table.addView(tr);
                } else {
                    if (updateIfExists == false) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                tr.removeAllViews();
                TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                textView.setText(displayString);
                tr.addView(textView);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks :)

Comment: I do not understand this: "even after the beacon is detected in the application,the didEnterRegion doesn't get called". How do you know the beacon is detected if the method does not get called?

Comment: @davidgyoung:- the assumption is made when the application lists the nearby beackon with its associated proximity uuid and its major and minor values.

Comment: OK, there must be some other code that displays the identifiers which is not shown above.  I suspect that this code may be interfering with the functioning of the code shown.  Can you please post the code that displays the beacon identifiers?

Comment: @davidgyoung : Sorry for the late reply. I have updated the code with the main Activity class now .Please let me know what I am doing wrong?Thanks

Comment: @davidgyoung : After updating the AndroidProximityLibrary I am now able to get the data associated with the nearby Beacon and the exit and entry region methods does get called only for the beacons whose  proximity UUID is given in the App.What If I need to get the details of other beacons as well with different UUIDs in my kit, I found that the methods for exit and entry never gets called for them. Also the notification that pops up when the application is in background doesn't show up at all. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [Proximity Kit for Android](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/proximitykit/), there are two separate sets of APIs available.  One set uses a `ProximityKitManager`, and it is intended for simpler use cases where you can pre-configure all of your iBeacon identifiers and associated data server-side, and let the `ProximityKitManager` handle setting up ranging and monitoring in a global Application class.

The second set of APIs use the `IBeaconManager` and provide more fine-grained control.  But because the `ProximityKitManager` uses the `IBeaconManager` under the hood, you should not use both at the same time, because you can easily break the automatic configuration done by `ProximityKitManager`.  I suspect that is what is causing your problem, because the code uses the `ProximityKitManager` in the Application class and `IBeaconManager` in the Activity class.  See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/proximity_kit.html) for more info.

If you need to track beacons regardless of the identifiers set up in ProximityKit, but still want to access the data configured for certain iBeacons in ProximityKit, you should not use the `ProximityKitManager` and instead just use the `IBeaconManager`.  There is a reference application that  shows how to access ProximityKit data using this API available [here.](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/proximity-reference-android)

Comment: Thanks for your response.I did manage to get all the details now.Right now I am facing an issue where if the application is running in the background then I am able to launch the application everytime an iBeacon is detected but it fails to launch if I terminate the App.So is there any possible way I can get the application working even when the user has terminated the app? iPhone seems to have covered this issue in iOS 7.1,wondering if I can do that in Android? I am a newbie in Android so dont know much about it.Thanks

Comment: The library will stop scanning temporarily on killing your app with the task switcher, but will automatically restart itself.  This is guaranteed to happen on the next boot, so an easy way to test is to restart your phone after killing the app.